# ASP.Net buttons reload entire page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I'm dabbling in some ASP.NET web paging stuff.  I'm a noob at this only starting yesterday.

I'm trying to write something basic, having a google map along with several locations that can be dropped via buttons.
I'm finding that when I press a button though, the marker drops but then the whole page reloaded and resets the google map window to its original initialized state.

Any suggestions, ideas, direction would be great.

Cheers

my java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.4679, 153.0277);
    var googleMapOptions;

    function initialize()
    {
        googleMapOptions =
        {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 15,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), googleMapOptions);
    }

    function addMyMarker()
    {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: "This a new marker!",
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });
        //alert('addMyMarker');
    }
</script>
```

my html/asp

```
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="z-index: 1; left: 46px; top: 102px; position: absolute; height: 440px; width: 481px">
    </div>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/WorldNormal.png" OnClick="OnClick" 
        OnMouseOver="src='images/WorldHighlight.png';" OnMouseOut="src='images/WorldNormal.png';" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 549px; top: 88px; position: absolute; width: 87px; height: 21px" />
</form>
</body>
```

code behind

```
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addMyMarker", "addMyMarker();", true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, asp.net buttons (usually) cause a postback because they are (usually) used to execute server-side code.  Why not just use a normal html button?  Doing a postback just to ultimately call a javascript function is a bit odd.

Comment: Might be odd indeed.  I'm still quite unfamiliar with the whole relationship of how postback server-side code all works.  This was the first example I found on the net and ran with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a `PostBack` and is a huge part of ASP.NET WebForms. You don't need it, though, since your `OnClick` method only adds some JS to run on the page. You can define the `OnClientClick` event for the button right on the page and avoid the PostBack.

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="addMyMarker(); return false;" />
```

(I removed the unimportant attributes on the tag to make my answer cleaner)

Note the `return false;` at the end - that tells the button to not do a `PostBack`.

Comment: This works a treat!  Thanks.  Just as a side question, are there ways to do server run code, maybe to refresh data from the server without doing a full page refresh?

Comment: Yes! The easy route is to use an `UpdatePanel`, which is a control in ASP.NET that allows for asynchronous updates. The more flexible, advanced approach is to use javascript (via XMLHttpRequest) or jQuery (which is easier than raw JS).